# CalledProcessError in Snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have a rule to run megahit genome assembler in my Snakemake pipeline:

```
rule perform_assembly_using_megahit:
  input:
    fq = "target.fq"
    
  output:
    fa    = "assembled_megahit/final.contigs.fa"
    
  threads:
    _NBR_CPUS
    
  run:
    command = MEGAHIT_DIR + "megahit -r " + input.fq + " -o " + _TEMP_DIR + "assembled_megahit/"
    shell(command)
```

and I got the following error:

```
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 374 of Snakefile:
Command 'set -euo pipefail;  ext/MEGAHIT-1.2.9-Linux-x86_64-static/bin/megahit -r target.fq -o assembled_megahit/' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

But if I run the same command on the CLI:

```
ext/MEGAHIT-1.2.9-Linux-x86_64-static/bin/megahit -r target.fq -o assembled_megahit/
```

the program runs without any problems. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exit code of the command? What if you run the `set -euo pipefail;` part beforehand as well?

Comment: Is your working directory the same in both cases?

Comment: I put the line shell.prefix("set -euo pipefail;") in my Snakefile before the first rule and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: As for the return code it says "returned non-zero exit status 1." And yes when I manually run the command it's in the same directory as my Snakefile. Also here's an observation that might be useful; before the error message I mentioned, it actually says "Output directory assembled_megahit already exists, please change the parameter -o to another value to avoid overwriting" even though I've deleted that directory before I run my Snakefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Output directory assembled_megahit already exists, please change the parameter -o to another value to avoid overwriting" even though I've deleted that directory before I run my Snakefile.

I believe snakemake creates the necessary directory tree for output files before executing the `run` directive. So you get the error even if you delete the output directory before running snakemake.

I think you can fix it with something like:

```
 run:
    outdir= _TEMP_DIR + "assembled_megahit/"
    shutil.rmtree(outdir)
 
    command = MEGAHIT_DIR + "megahit -r " + input.fq + " -o " + outdir
    shell(command)
```

(Obviously it assumes there isn't anything valuable inside `outdir`)